# Store Unicode data in SQL Server 2008 XML datatype

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, unicode

I have XML data type as a table column. I have stored some XML text inside it. The XML text contains some Hebrew characters, but after I store it in the table, all the Hebrew characters are turned to “?”. What can I do to fix it?

This is my UPDATE statement:

```
update db_owner.Screen_Template set template_xml = 
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Screen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../GUIGenerator_V2/Scheme/GG_Scheme.xsd">
        <Legend EntityType="Request">
            <Module ForceTabs="1">
                <Events>
                    <Event Value="onafter_moduleinit_beforedraw()" Type="onafter_moduleinit_beforedraw"/>
                </Events>
                <Section Id="Header" Type="header" Caption="Header" ContainerCSS="background:#C1E0F4;border-bottom:2px groove;margin-bottom:3px;padding:10 3 3 3">
                    <Containers>
                        <Form Id="Header" Caption="General Details" Source="Request" Layout="Fixed">
                            <Layout>
                                <table cellaspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <ControlRef Id="Origin" ShowCaption="1"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <ControlRef Id="Type" ShowCaption="1"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <ControlRef Id="Process" ShowCaption="1"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="20" align="center">
                                            <span class="separator"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <ControlRef Id="FindBy" ShowCaption="1"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <ControlRef Id="Find"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button width="30" onclick="doFindCustomer()">
                                                <Caption Caption="GO"/>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </Layout>
                            <Controls>
                                <Control Id="Origin" Caption="Origin" FieldName="Origin" DataType="string" Width="90" CaptionWidth="70" ReadOnly="1" Mandatory="1" Hidden="1"/>
                                <Control Id="Type" Caption="Type" FieldName="Type" DataType="select" Width="60" CaptionWidth="40" ReadOnly="1" Mandatory="1" DefaultValue="Service" Hidden="1">
                                    <Member Value="Allert" Caption="Allert"/>
                                    <Member Value="Service" Caption="Service"/>
                                    <Member Value="Marketing" Caption="Marketing"/>
                                </Control>
                                <Control Id="Process" Caption="Process" FieldName="Process" DataType="string" Width="90" CaptionWidth="70" ReadOnly="1" Mandatory="1" Hidden="1"/>
                                <Control Id="FindBy" Caption="Find:" VCaption="Find By" FieldName="FindBy" DataType="select" Width="90" CaptionWidth="50" ReadOnly="0" Mandatory="0" CaptionCSS="font-weight:bold" DefaultValue="IMTSI">
                                    <Member Value="IMTSI" Caption="IMTSI"/>
                                    <Member Value="ID" Caption="ID"/>
                                </Control>
                                <Control Id="Find" Caption="Find Value" FieldName="Find" DataType="string" Width="90" CaptionWidth="60" ReadOnly="0" Mandatory="0" CaptionCSS="font-weight:bold"/>
                            </Controls>
                        </Form>
                    </Containers>
                </Section>
                <Section Id="1" Type="page" Caption="tech visit sms reminder">
                    <Containers>
                        <Form Id="General" Caption="General Details" Source="Request" Layout="Fixed">
                            <Controls>
                                <Control Id="IMTSI" Caption="IMTSI" Source="Param[@Name = ''IMTSI'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="120" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" Mandatory="0" Hidden="1"/>
                                <Control Id="MessageType" Caption="Message Type" Source="Param[@Name = ''MessageType'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="select" Width="150" CaptionWidth="120" ReadOnly="1" Mandatory="1" DefaultValue="Allert" Action="handleMessageTypeChange()" BreakAfter="1">
                                    <Member Value="SMS" Caption="SMS"/>
                                    <Member Value="EMAIL" Caption="EMAIL"/>
                                    <Member Value="ATOS" Caption="ATOS"/>
                                    <Member Value="SELF SERVICE" Caption="SELF SERVICE"/>
                                </Control>
                                <Control Id="Language" Caption="Language" Source="Param[@Name = ''Language'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="select" Width="120" CaptionWidth="120" ReadOnly="0" BreakAfter="1" SelectionType="single" Hidden="0" SeparateAfter="1">
                                    <Member Value="heb" Caption="heb"/>
                                    <Member Value="eng" Caption="eng"/>
                                </Control>
                                <Control Id="Mobile" Caption="Mobile" Source="Param[@Name = ''Mobile'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="120" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" Mandatory="1" SeparateAfter="0"/>
                                <Control Id="FirstName" Caption="First Name" Source="Param[@Name = ''FirstName'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="120" BreakAfter="1" CaptionWidth="120" Mandatory="1"/>
                                <Control Id="Visitday" Caption="Visit day" Source="Param[@Name = ''Visitday'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="select" Width="120" CaptionWidth="120" ReadOnly="0" BreakAfter="1" Mandatory="1" SeparateBefore="1" SeparateAfter="1">
                                    <Member Value="&#x5D0;" Caption="&#x5E8;&#x5D0;&#x5E9;&#x5D5;&#x5DF;"/>
                                    <Member Value="&#x5D1;" Caption="&#x5E9;&#x5E0;&#x5D9;"/>
                                    <Member Value="&#x5D2;" Caption="&#x5E9;&#x5DC;&#x5D9;&#x5E9;&#x5D9;"/>
                                    <Member Value="&#x5D3;" Caption="&#x5E8;&#x5D1;&#x5D9;&#x5E2;&#x5D9;"/>
                                    <Member Value="&#x5D4;" Caption="&#x5D7;&#x5DE;&#x5D9;&#x5E9;&#x5D9;"/>
                                </Control>
                                <Control Id="Date" Caption="Visit date" Source="Param[@Name = ''Date'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="date" EnableTime="0" Width="120" CaptionWidth="120" Height="60" BreakAfter="1" MaxLen="20" Mandatory="1" SeparateBefore="1" SeparateAfter="1"/>
                                <Control Id="Visithours" Caption="Visit hours" Source="Param[@Name = ''Visithours'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" EnableTime="1" Width="120" CaptionWidth="120" Height="60" BreakAfter="1" MaxLen="20" Mandatory="1" SeparateBefore="1" SeparateAfter="1"/>
                                <Control Id="Email" Caption="Email" Source="Param[@Name = ''Email'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" Mandatory="0" Hidden="1"/>
                                <Control Id="Subject" Caption="Subject" Source="Param[@Name = ''Subject'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" MaxLen="40" Hidden="1"/>
                                <Control Id="Sender" Caption="Sender" Source="Param[@Name = ''Sender'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" ReadOnly="1" BreakAfter="1"/>
                                <Control Id="Priority" Caption="Priority" Source="Param[@Name = ''Priority'']" FieldName="Value" DataType="select" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" DefaultValue="LOW" Hidden="1">
                                    <Member Value="LOW" Caption="Low" Glyf="../../GUIGenerator_V2/assets/themes/Images/flag_blue.png"/>
                                    <Member Value="MED" Caption="Medium" Glyf="../../GUIGenerator_V2/assets/themes/Images/flag_yellow.png"/>
                                    <Member Value="HIGH" Caption="High" Glyf="../../GUIGenerator_V2/assets/themes/Images/flag_red.png"/>
                                </Control>
                            </Controls>
                        </Form>
                    </Containers>
                </Section>
            </Module>
            <DefaultData>
                <Request Origin="ISRAEL" Type="Service" Process="17">
                    <Param Name="MessageType" Type="Field" Value="SMS"/>
                    <Param Name="FirstName" Type="Field"/>
                    <Param Name="Visitday" Type="Field"/>
                    <Param Name="Date" Type="Field"/>
                    <Param Name="Visithours" Type="Field"/>
                    <Param Name="Mobile" Type="Field"/>
                    <Param Name="Sender" Type="Field" Value="BTP|*5755"/>
                    <Param Name="Priority" Type="Field" Value="LOW"/>
                    <Param Name="Language" Type="Field" Value="heb"/>
                </Request>
            </DefaultData>
        </Legend>
        <Data/>
    </Screen>'
where UID like '4'
```

and the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Screen_Template WHERE env LIKE '" + env + "' AND OpCo LIKE '" + opco + "' AND UID LIKE '" + uid + "'"
```

Comment: The XML datatype stores everything in UCS-2 unicode (2 bytes per char), so basically it should be able to handle hebrew characters just fine. How did you **insert** the data into that XML column?

Comment: By using update statement I have tried to add 'N' before the xml text but still it changed every hebrew character to '?'

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xml` data type has full support for Unicode and will not convert letters to question marks. Something else is going on. It could be one of the following reasons.

1. Your OS does not have the correct fonts for Hebrew.
2. The `INSERT` part of your client app is corrupting the source data into a single-byte character set (e.g using varchar instead of nvarchar).
3. The `SELECT` part of your client app is corrupting the table data into a single-byte character set (e.g using varchar instead of nvarchar).

*Update based on poster's new code sample:*

Your INSERT statement is corrupting Unicode text by using single-byte string constants e.g. 'text' instead of Unicode constants e.g. N'some text'. You need to prefix all string literals with a capital N to ensure uNicode is used.

```
UPDATE db_owner.Screen_Template
SET template_xml = 
N'<Screen> ... </Screen>'
```

Comment: can I alter an XML data type collation?

Comment: If you're using Unicode data types (i.e. nvarchar and xml) and Unicode constants (e.g. N'אא') then there's no need to worry about collation.

Comment: To fix your client application, make sure you're using Unicode data types and constants everywhere.

Comment: The problem is with the DB because when I'm making the Update statement, the database stores the xml with '?' characters instead of hebrew characters

Comment: I'm making the statement at the DB itself !

Comment: Post your UPDATE statement and your SELECT statement

Comment: posted in the original message

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: String literals need to be prefixed with a capital N.